# How to handle multiple SOAP requests in the same envelope using Java Web Service?

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I currently have a web service with the method:

```
@Override
@WebResult(Name="OIPResponse")
public  Map<String, Object> getOIP(@WebParam(name = "invoice") String invoiceNumber,@WebParam(name = "part") String partNumber)
```

The normal SOAP request I use to call it looks like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:oip="http://oip.mycompany.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <oip:getOIP>
         <invoice>41587182</invoice>
         <part>9ZF2A5-570</part>
      </oip:getOIP>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

and the response is something like this:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <ns2:getOIPResponse xmlns:ns2="http://oip.mycompany.com/">
            <OIPResponse>
                <entry>
                    <key>ERR_CODE</key>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <key>SELLING_OU</key>
                    <value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">null</value>
                </entry>
                ...
            </OIPResponse>
        </ns2:getOIPResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I've tested this and it works fine.  Now I am wondering if there is a way to include multiple requests in the same SOAP envelope like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:oip="http://oip.mycompany.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <oip:getOIP>
         <invoice>41587182</invoice>
         <part>9ZF2A5-570</part>
      </oip:getOIP>
      <oip:getOIP>
         <invoice>41587183</invoice>
         <part>9ZF2A5-570</part>
      </oip:getOIP>
      <oip:getOIP>
         <invoice>41587184</invoice>
         <part>9ZF2A5-570</part>
      </oip:getOIP>
      <oip:getOIP>
         <invoice>41587185</invoice>
         <part>9ZF2A5-570</part>
      </oip:getOIP>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

and get back something like this:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <ns2:getOIPResponse xmlns:ns2="http://oip.mycompany.com/">
            <OIPResponse>
               ...
            </OIPResponse>
            <OIPResponse>
               ...
            </OIPResponse>
            <OIPResponse>
               ...
            </OIPResponse>
               ...
        </ns2:getOIPResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Can't you modify the operation to accept the list instead of  a single invoice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a POJO called OIPRequest that contained the two parameters I need (invoice and part number) and a new method getOIPMultiple which takes an array of OIPRequests as an input parameter.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class OIPRequest {
    public String invoiceNumber, partNumber;

    public OIPRequest(String invoice, String part) {
        invoiceNumber = invoice;
        partNumber = part;
    }

    public OIPRequest() {
        invoiceNumber = "";
        partNumber = "";
    }
}
```

This makes the request look like this:

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Body>
        <getMultipleOIP xmlns="http://oip.mycompany.com/">
            <OIPRequest xmlns="">
                <invoiceNumber>41587182</invoiceNumber>
                <partNumber>9ZF2A5-570</partNumber>
            </OIPRequest>
            <OIPRequest xmlns="">
                <invoiceNumber>41587182</invoiceNumber>
                <partNumber>9ZF2A5-570</partNumber>
            </OIPRequest>
            <OIPRequest xmlns="">
                <invoiceNumber>41587182</invoiceNumber>
                <partNumber>9ZF2A5-570</partNumber>
            </OIPRequest>
        </getMultipleOIP>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```